# Figure Size getting changed when zooming in matplotlib using "zoom to rectangle" option

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am using the following code to plot Basemap using matplotlib in python.

```
import os

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r"C:\Users\Anaconda3\pkgs\proj4-6.0.0-ha7a8c7b_0\Library\share\proj"; 

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map= Basemap(projection='cyl',
    llcrnrlon = -180, llcrnrlat = -90,
    urcrnrlon = 180, urcrnrlat = 90,
            resolution='l')

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='#ddaa66',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()

map.drawparallels(range(-90, 90, 20), labels = [False, True, True, False])
map.drawmeridians(range(-180, 180, 20), labels = [True, False, False, True])

plt.show()
```

Issue which I am facing is that when I am trying to zoom in to a particular section of the map using "Zoom to Rectangle" option, the figure size is getting changed.

Here are the figures which shows what issue exactly I am facing:

[image: Orginal Image before using 'Zoom to Rectangle' feature in matplotlib plot]

[image: Image after using the 'Zoom to Rectangle' feature in matplotlib which depicts the figure size getting reduced]

Can someone tell me how we can zoom in to a particular section/region of the map without altering the figure size.